# Security Scan for remote site

Tags: visualforce, security, security-review, chimera-security-scanner

Can you please help me running scan for a remote site setting. SFDC asked for chimera report for remote Site setting.

eg. I have a remote site setting with URL as: https://abc.abc.com and which  gets pointed in rest-call Outs in APEX.

When i run chimera scan for same, its ask for user name and password, but Site owner not ready to provide credentials.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanned using Zap scanner.

Thanks

Comment: did just simply added the URL and ran attack or did you launch the browser and then typed the URL ?? share your knowledge